# Is there only one complex structure on complex plane $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

There is a trivial complex structure on $\mathbb{C}$.

Do we have other complex structures on complex plane $\mathbb{C}$?

If not, how to prove it?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ is not a complex plane, it is a real plane. The complex plane is $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: (Despite the title, the answer is no.)

Comment: @C.Falcon That's technically correct, $\mathbb C$ is the algebra ($\mathbb R^2$,+, *) with the modulus distance function on the complex numbers. But when beginners refer to the complex numbers,they usually call it the complex or Argand plane. So unless it's qualified otherwise, "the complex plane" means this algebra/metric space.